# Change color of the object based on previous player's choice?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I've have 2 scenes in my Unity project with selection choice. To access the scene second with for example weapons, you have to choose character in the first scene. I would like to change color of the weapons based on which character I choose in the character selection scene. How do I approach this if everything works on arrays ?
Here's my script with that I implement in character selection scene:

```
 {
     private GameObject[] characterList;
     private int index;

     private void Start()
     {
         index = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CharacterSelected");

         characterList = new GameObject[transform.childCount];

         //array w players
         for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)

             characterList[i] = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;

         foreach (GameObject go in characterList)

             go.SetActive(false);
             if (characterList[index])
                 characterList[index].SetActive(true);


     }

     public void ToggleLeft()
     {
         characterList[index].SetActive(false);  //turning off the old character

         index --;
         if (index < 0)
             index = characterList.Length - 1;

         characterList[index].SetActive(true);

     }

      public void ToggleRight()
     {
         characterList[index].SetActive(false);  //turning off the old character

         index++;
         if (index == characterList.Length)
             index = 0;
             characterList[index].SetActive(true);

     }

     public void GoBackToCharacter()
     {

         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CharacterSelected", index);
         SceneManager.LoadScene("WeaponSelect");


     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question relates to persisting state throughout the application. I would suggest using a static class to retain character properties throughout the lifetime of your application (scene 1 and scene 2), and access the applicable property when necessary. A basic example follows:

```
public static class CharacaterClass
 {
   public static string Weapon {get; set; }
   public static string Color {get; set; }
 }
```

Set a characters weapon in scene1 (Form1)

```
 Character.Weapon = "gun";
```

then grab that characters weapon in scene2 (Form2)

```
 var charWeapon = Character.Weapon;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I don't quite know how this could work in my case